# Apache Tika extract only field names from PDF XFA forms but not the text content

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, apache-tika, xfa

I have tried to use **Apache Tika v1.14** to parse text contained in PDF XFA forms. However, after trying different configuration in `PDFParserConfig`, I can only get the field names but not the text content of those fields.

For example, if there's a field called "Telephone", part of Tika's output may be `<li fieldName="Telephone">Telephone: </li>` (the same repeats for other fields as well). However, if I use **pdfbox** API to traverse the DOM tree to reach the Node named "Telephone", then I can use `getNodeValue()` to obtain the text content I want.

I am aware of the settings `setExtractAcroFormContent()` and `setIfXFAExtractOnlyXFA()` in `PDFParserConfig` and also experimented with them but I still didn't get the text content.

So my questions are

- Did I misconfigure Tika so that it does not give the right output? Or,
- Is this what Apache Tika's implementation is intended to do? Or,
- Is the implementation still under development?

I am sorry that the forms contain medical information of patients so I am not able to attach them as example.

Thank you very much.

p.s. I am also aware of Tika's Jira issues https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-973 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1857 so I thought this feature has been implemented.

Comment: Do you need the text of the PDF as well as the field name/value pairs in context or do you just need to get at the form data?

Comment: Form data are the priority, ideally in field name / value pairs. It is okay to not have the form "template" which is fixed.

Comment: If you're looking for the form data name/value pairs, PDFBox is probably a better solution for you than Tika. You don't even need to parse the DOM. You can easily get the datasets from the XFA object and you'll have the XML of the data in a format that's easy to parse.

Comment: Oh, would you point me to the classes / methods for "get the datasets from the XFA object" ? Currently I am parsing all the `#text` node in the DOM tree in a depth-first search fashion.

Comment: In PDFBox use PDXFAResource.getBytes(). That'll give you the XML. Then you just use whatever XLM library you want to parse it to get the dataset.